# Should I change socket options on the original socket or the new one?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

Consider the following python script:

```
import socket
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9999))
s.listen()
connections = []

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    connections.append(conn)
    # send and receive data using open connections
```

According to the `socket` documentation:

> socket.accept()
>
> Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an
> address and listening for connections. The return value is a pair
> (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to send and
> receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to
> the socket on the other end of the connection.

Now suppose I want to change the socket options, like:

```
setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 2048)
```

Should I call this method on the original socket `s`, the new connection `conn` or both of them?

Comment: You change the options on the socket you use to communicate (i.e., the new one). There is no parent-child relationship between sockets, options are not inherited, much less retroactively.

Comment: You are right, I edited the title